# Using function to change color based on Boolean value in another function in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, boolean

I have a function that returns something like this :

```
let checkAddedValuesFunction =
```

```
{"444" => Array(1), "T" => Array(1), ":778" => Array(1)}

0: {"444" => Array(1)}
key: "444"
  value: Array(1)
  0: {isValue: true, string: "111:222:444", at: 8}

1: {"T" => Array(1)}
key: "T"
 value: Array(1)
 0: {isValue: false, string: "SQL_DT", at: 5}

2: {":778" => Array(1)}
```

I'm trying to create a function that will change color of the elements in the string based on isValue true/false statement. I'm currently doing something like this but it seems to be not working at all:

```
    const changeColor = (target) => {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(checkAddedValuesFunction)) {

        ~~// FIND IF VALUE IS TRUE THEN GO AND CHANGE COLOR //~~

        if (document.querySelector(".compareKey")) {
          document.querySelector(".compareKey").style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else if (document.getElementsByClassName(".compareValue")) {
          document.getElementsByClassName(".compareValue").style.backgroundColor =
            "red";
        }
      }

    };
```

Comment: `{"444" => Array(1)}` is not valid JavaScript. Is this your exact code?

Comment: ```Map(3) {"444" => Array(1), "T" => Array(1), ":778" => Array(1)}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many little mistakes in your code:

- `.querySelector()` returns only the first matching item, you should use `.querySelectorAll()`
- You cannot access the `.style` property of a nodelist, you have to loop the nodelist and access each node individually
- `.getElementsByClassName()` take the class name as argument, so without the `.`

Here is a small reduced example:

```js
function changeElementsBgColor(elements, color) {
  for(let i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}

if (document.querySelector(".compareKey")) {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".compareKey")
  changeElementsBgColor(elements, "red");
}

if (document.getElementsByClassName("compareValue")) {
  const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("compareValue");    changeElementsBgColor(elements, "red");
}
```

```html
<h1 class="compareKey">compareKey element 1</h1>
<h1 class="compareKey">compareKey element 2</h1>
<h1 class="compareValue">compareValue element 1</h1>
<h1 class="compareValue">compareValue element 2</h1>
```

Comment: thank you that really makes things easier, however my main question is to change color based on boolean isValue in the first function.

Comment: seems you have to check `if (value[0].isValue)`

Comment: I don't really understand how can I loop through [0],[1],[2]..etc..

Comment: Because in your map the value item is an array. Now i don't know if there can be multiple values, but seems that you need to access only the first one

Comment: hey, thanks again for ur reply, I need to access all of them though

Comment: then you just have to loop inside a loop to check all the variables and use logical operators to combine the values